# `rcond` parameter will change to the default of machine precision times ``max(M, N)`` where M and N are the input matrix dimensions

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I migrated some large piece of code from Python 2.7 to Python 3.7, and now I am getting

> `rcond` parameter will change to the default of machine precision
>   times `max(M, N)` where M and N are the input matrix dimensions. To
>   use the future default and silence this warning we advise to pass
>   `rcond=None`, to keep using the old, explicitly pass `rcond=-1`.

There is no line number, or even a file, and I have no idea what is causing this.

according to [this github thread](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/py-earth/issues/194),

> These warnings are currently nothing to worry about. They are fixed in
>   the v0.2dev branch. That branch is not yet ready to be released
>   because of issues with scikit-learn compatibility, but you could use
>   it if you're concerned about the warnings.

---

1. Are they really nothing to worry about?
2. How can I get rid of them without suppressing all warnings?
3. How to find the line that causes them?

Answer (score 5):

You can suppress this warning by changing `np.linalg.lstsq(a, b)` to `np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)`
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html

Comment: This is good, but it would be useful to see a discussion/explanation of what it means. E.g., what is `rcond`, what is 'machine precision times', and what does it have to do with `rcond`, etc.

Comment: @eric Which is explained in the numpy documentation: rcondfloat, optional

    Cut-off ratio for small singular values of a. For the purposes of rank determination, singular values are treated as zero if they are smaller than rcond times the largest singular value of a.

    Changed in version 1.14.0: If not set, a FutureWarning is given. The previous default of -1 will use the machine precision as rcond parameter, the new default will use the machine precision times max(M, N). To silence the warning and use the new default, use rcond=None, to keep using the old behavior, use rcond=-1.